# Avoid deepcopy() in Python when changing dictionary

Tags: python, parsing, runtime

I am looking for a solution to avoid deepcopy() in my task using Python.

I am implementing a statistical dependency parser using chu-liu-edmonds algorithm. I have a graph represented as a dictionary with every head node stored as a key with each having a list containing one or more objects of the class arc as the value.

In the cle-algorithm, I need to modify the graph (contract a cycle). That means, that I need to delete arc objects and heads, and add others, while I later need the original graph to expand those contracted cycles. Right now, I achieve this by deepcopying the original graph and pass it to the contract function.

Now I ran my programm with cProfile and found out that everything that has to do with deepcopy is by far the part of the algorithm that takes the most time.

So my question is: Is there any way to avoid/reduce this in my situation?

Comment: If the changes you make during contraction have to be done in place and you have to maintain the original graph, I don't think it is possible to prevent the need for a second copy of the graph either by loading it twice at the start or making a deep copy.  

Is it possible to build the contracted graph as a new graph as you go through the process or otherwise store the information necessary to make the conversion as needed, rather than actually store the contracted graph itself?

Comment: As I think about it, it might be the best way to try to build the new one up rather than copying the old one and alter it. It actually never occured to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @dmargol1 suggested in the comments, I was able to avoid deepcopy() and copy() by instead building the graph from scratch, rather than copying and modifying it, which was actually a lot faster.

If that is possible: do it!

If copying is neccessary, there are two ways. If you don't need to alter the values, copy() is the way to go, since it is a lot faster than deepcopy() (see the comment of @george-solymosi). If alteration of the values is needed, deepcopy is the only way (see the comment of @gall).

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**
If you want to alter lists in dict you can't avoid **deepcopy()** but you should do the following:

"Save" only the value of **alterable/deletable elements**(i.e. lists) of graph, **not** the **full graph**. Then make the required modification on the dict/graph, then you can use the "saved" elements for further modification of graph.

Use `dict.copy()`, as you can see below the the d.copy() is 100000x s faster:

```
from copy import deepcopy
from time import time

# with simply assignment -------------

d = {"a":[x for x in range(1000000)]}

t = time()
e = d
print 'elapsed time with standard assignment:', time()-t

e["b"] = [1,2,3]
del e["a"]
print d.keys()

# with deepcopy() --------------------

d = {"a":[x for x in range(1000000)]}

t = time()
e = deepcopy(d)
print '\nelapsed time with deepcopy():', time()-t

e["b"] = [1,2,3]
del e["a"]
print d.keys()

# with d.copy() ---------------------

d = {"a":[x for x in range(1000000)]}

t = time()
e = d.copy()
print '\nelapsed time with d.copy():', time()-t

e["b"] = [1,2,3]
del e["a"]
print d.keys()
```

**Output:**

```
elapsed time with standard assignment: 0.000110149383545
['b']

elapsed time with deepcopy(): 1.78457307816
['a']

elapsed time with d.copy(): 2.09808349609e-05
['a']
```

Comment: But ``dict.copy()`` does a shallow copy which is not the desired behavior in this case of nested structure.

Comment: @Gall As you can see from my example's output `dict.copy()` does the job exactly which is the desired by us. i.e. the future modifying **doesn't alter** the **original** dictionary, thus does the same job as we expect from `deepcopy()`.

Comment: If you don't have to alter the list value yes, otherwise no.

Comment: @Gall Of course I know as well that otherwise not the same functionality, since the one is deep and the other is shallow. But it seemed to me the OP tended to be use deepcopy for this functionality.

Comment: I see, you might want to mention it in your answer then to make it clear because that's not what I understand from the OP's question.

Comment: OP says "That means, that I need to delete arc objects and heads, and add others, while I later need the original graph to expand those contracted cycles" and then  "achieve this by deepcopying" then " Is there any way to avoid". I interpreted the task by these keywords. But, could you please tell your version? Then I rethink yet and update my answer, if has to. Thanks

Comment: I need to alter the list values, so copy is not applicable here.

Comment: @YanickNedderhoff In this case you can't avoid, but see my update:

Comment: Actually I maybe can, but that is because I apparently don't necessarly need a copy and alter it. Insted, I also can build up a new one from scratch. (see my answer to @dmargol1.).
But that is only working in my special case. More generally speaking, it seems that you are right. If you **have to** copy it and can't find a way to build the second one from scratch, deepcopy() is the way to go.